# What if someone substantially edits your answer, removing several key pieces of information, while admittedly improving some typos?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

A question requested multiple answers to problems upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, "Please list your experiences".  Since my experience was not represented, I added an answer of medium quality.  Since then, it has been edited.  This is fine.  However, the editor removed several key pieces of information:

- The version of Ubuntu that worked despite the wrong "Secure Boot" mode.
- The fact that I'm using proprietary NVidia drivers, which are specifically what did not work after the upgrade.
- The actual change that fixed it.  (They said I disabled Secure Boot; I actually changed it from "Windows" mode to "Other")

The keywords they removed are essentially the keywords I had been searching hours earlier, to no avail; removing them makes the answer much less useful, at least to people like me.

I'm going to edit their edit, keeping the formatting improvements, but making the answer relevant again.  Am I right to do this?  Or am I being a bad citizen in some way?

Answer in question: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/763493#763493)

Comment: I think any question that asks users to "Please list your experiences" should be closed as Too Broad on most sites.

Comment: @PolyGeo I agree, but I felt inclined to answer anyway, since the upgrade had caused real pain that had a real solution.

Comment: Then, either as the poster or as a user with 2k reputation, you should "rollback" the edit, and fix the typos. Rollbacking is undoing the edit. Here's how to rollback: near the top of the edit page, there is a list of all the edits that have ever been done. You can select the older one from that list and press "save edits"